# Past medical/medication history in MIMIC-III

Tags: mimic-iii

Aside from progress notes (using natural language analysis or by manual review), is there any method for extracting past medical history or a medication history prior to admission from the [MIMIC-III database](https://mimic.physionet.org/)?

In looking at the D_ITEMS table, I found a few relevant ITEMID values (225059 - "Past medical history" and 225811 - "CV - past medical history"), but there are no items in CHARTEVENTS that correspond to these ITEMID values.

Comment: Does the two itemids work for both metavision and careview data? The database is mentioned as metavision on both of these item_ids!

Comment: Something of note: The database probably has a glitch, None of the patients have diabetes on oral medicines without insulin per PMHX fields - quite unlikely :) FYI Mimic coordinators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data was unavailable in v1.3 but has now been added and is available in v1.4 (released Sept 2nd 2016).

Comment: For anyone interested in this (ITEMID 225059 or 225811), the following "values" are available as past medical history flags: Anemia, Angina, Arrhythmias, Asthma, CAD, CHF, COPD, CVA, Diabetes - Insulin, Diabetes - Oral Agent, ETOH, GI Bleed, HEMO or PD, Hepatitis, Hypertension, Liver Failure, MI, Pacemaker, Pancreatitis, PVD, Renal Failure, Seizures, Smoker

Comment: In these itemid, I did not find about medication in use, only about comorbidities. Where can I find about previous medication in use? Best

Comment: Your best bet is a free-text search of the discharge summaries, which usually have a section called "admission medications". There is some code to give you a head start, if you know python: https://github.com/mghassem/medicationCategories